# Disable all linkbutton and checkbox on the page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a gridview that has 2 link buttons : Select and edit and 1 checkbox i need to disable the link buttons and the checkbox when the page loads

this is my asp page:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>


                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox id="Select" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="false"/>
                      <asp:LinkButton  ID="idedit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"
                            ToolTip="Edit"  Text="Edit"/>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>

                 <asp:LinkButton  ID="idupdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Update"
                            ToolTip="Update" OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('Are you sure do you want to update this?')){return false;}" />
                        <asp:LinkButton  ID="idcancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"
                            Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

this is my vb code :

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("priv") = "host" Then
        fname_txt.Visible = False
        lname_txt.Visible = False
        email_txt.Visible = False
        birthday_txt.Visible = False
        phone_txt.Visible = False
        adresss_txt.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        Label4.Visible = False
        Label5.Visible = False
        Label6.Visible = False
        Label7.Visible = False
        btn_delete.Visible = False
        btn_new.Visible = False
        Btn_save.Visible = False
    End If
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataSource = x.selectProfile()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `RowDataBound` event of the grid like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server">
</asp:gridview>
```

Note: This tells the `GridView` that when each row is bound you want the method `GridView1_RowDataBound` to handle that event.

Code-behind:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' Only deal with data rows, ignore header rows, footer rows, etc.
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' If the user is a certain role, then do the following logic; otherwise do not
        If User.IsInRole("Administrators") Then
            ' Find the edit link button
            Dim theEditLinkButton As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("idedit"), LinkButton)

            ' Disable the edit link button
            theEditLinkButton.Enabled = False
        End If    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't need to do that all the time ... it depends on the authentication ... some users can the see the linkbuttons and others can't..

Comment: Then add conditional logic in my answer to only disable things if the user is a certain role. See updated answer.

Comment: If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to up-vote the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be from the template editor in the designer... go to Template Editor > Item Template, click on the linkbutton/check box and change it to visible = false in the properties.

Comment: well no because i sometimes need it disabled and sometimes enabled depending on the authentication